# How to read xlsx file into R and convert it into tsibble object?

Tags: r, tsibble

I would like to  read a xlsx file  into R, and create a tsibble object. It looks like this:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/119RXtTVJbHYeivorEtApbxQrLkLXolZdOc0kgCXFljQ/edit?usp=sharing

How can I do it ?

Comment: Did you read the data in R? After you do that you can use `tsibble::as_tsibble()` to convert it into `tsibble` object.

Comment: @RonakShah I did. When I use as_tsibble() after reading the file (df=readxl::read_xlsx()) I get: "Can't obtain the interval due to the mismatched index class."

Comment: @Brutalroot Thanks, but how do I convert it to understandable format of (01.12.2018) instead of numeric 43435..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
library("openxlsx")
library("tsibble")

df <- data.frame(read.xlsx("Data.xlsx"))

tsibble <- as_tsibble(df, index = Date)

#Fuction to convert Date column to date format
tsibble$Date <- as.Date(tsibble$Date, origin = "1989-12-30")
```